# MySQL replace result value with another value

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when, ansi-sql

I have MySQL and the query is:

```
select name,re_type from myTable
```

I want to replace all values of type:

```
1 = student
2 = teacher
```

So the result should be:

```
name    re_type
---------------
Ron     Student
Mac     Teacher
```

Not like:

```
name    re_type
---------------
Ron     1
Mac     2
```

Is it possible to make a query like that so I get the desired result in MySQL ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN re_type = 1 THEN 'Student' WHEN re_type = 2 THEN 'Teacher' ELSE 'Donno' END AS re_type_text
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a joint table that will store labels for your re_type like

```
re_type_id  re_type_label
1           student
2           teacher
```

And alter your query by :

```
select t.name,l.re_type_label
from myTable t
inner join labelsTable l
    on l.re_type_id = t.re_type
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he wants to keep IDs on re_type field, and just decoding them when extracting.

You can use CASE WHEN or ELT(), MySql equivalent to Oracle's Decode(), like explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_elt)

, but the Best Practice is to create an external table containing re_type and re_type_description fields, so if tomorrow you'll have new values, you don't have to change all your queries.